# Gulp error: Path must be a string

Tags: laravel, gulp, zurb-foundation

I've got a problem with gulp.js.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
$ laravel new myproject
$ cd myproject
$ php artisan serve 
$ npm install
$ npm rm bootstrap-sass —save
$ npm install foundation-sites —save
$ npm install motion-ui —save
```

then I copy

```
_settings.scss
```

from

```
node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings
```

to

```
resources/assets/sass
```

in app.scss then i put every Foundation import

and finally I write Elixir task as reported here:

http://zecipriano.com/en/2015/12/laravel-elixir-and-zurb-foundation-revisited/

But when I launch gulp from terminal:

```
 path.js:7
  throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
```

... don't know what to do.

Everything updated, so I think it's not a version problem.

**[EDIT]**

```
$ node -v

v6.8.0
```

and here's my gulpfile.js:

```js
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {

    // Sass
    var options = {
        includePaths: [
            'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
            'node_modules/motion-ui/src'
        ]
    };

    mix.sass('app.scss', null, options);

    // Javascript
    var jQuery = '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
    var foundationJsFolder = '../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/js/';

    mix.scripts([
       jQuery,
       foundationJsFolder + 'foundation.core.js',
       // Include any needed components here. The following are just examples.
       foundationJsFolder + 'foundation.util.mediaquery.js',
       foundationJsFolder + 'foundation.util.keyboard.js',
       foundationJsFolder + 'foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js',
       foundationJsFolder + 'foundation.tabs.js',
       // This file initializes foundation
       'start_foundation.js'
    ]);

});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error appears to be a node error, not a gulp error. Can you post your node version - `node -v` - and the contents of your gulp.js file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I've added details in my main question.

Comment: There appears to be an issue involving nodeJs v6+ and gulp. If your application is not dependent on node v6 then you could downgrade from node v6.8.0 to v5.11.1 by running `nvm install 5` followed by `nvm use 5` - provided you have node version manager installed. You can check if nvm is installed via the `nvm -v` command.

Comment: You could also try manually passing the directory string to `mix.sass` - something like `mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/assets/css', options);` - as the error is asking for a string when you have given a null type.

Comment: Tried everything you typed with no luck, alas. Thank you btw.

Comment: Are you definitely using node 5.x now?

Comment: What version of laravel have you installed (i'll try reproduce the issue) and what is the contents of your package.json?

Comment: Thank you Bill, really! Yes, I'm using Node v5.12.0, Laravel Installer version 1.3.3 and this is my... oh, well, while writing this reply a friend found the solution. 

He's typing it now. PARAMS moved from 3 to 4. Two "null" needed. Argh.

Comment: Odd. I replicated with one null value (also passing an explicit path string) and it worked fine. Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the options have been moved from the third to the fourth parameter. You can run it with:

```
   mix.sass('app.scss', null, null, options);
```

Cheers :D

Comment: Mate, I found this post by accident and you saved me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40445663/4197938 big thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Where do I find this information in the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#sass)?

Comment: Found it here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/setting-include-path-for-sass-in-elixir

Answer (score 0):

I have the node 4.4.2 installed and countered the same error. Then I passed the the directory string directly instead of using an array with directions.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @DieterMeemken for instance, it was .less('admin.less',bowerDir, { paths: adminLess }) where adminLess is a variable I defined as var adminLess =[ path1,path2,path3]; and it report error. after i changed to .less('admin.less',bowerDir, path1,path2,path3) i worked.