# Running gulp gives "path.js:7 throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

In my Wordpress project I'm using **Laravel Elixir** to deal with assets. Everything was working till today.

Now every time I run `gulp` I'm getting:

```
$ gulp
path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { includePaths:
   [ 'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/',
     'bower_components/slick-carousel/slick' ] }
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1211:7)
    at prefixOne (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/GulpPaths.js:143:43)
    at GulpPaths.prefix (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/GulpPaths.js:153:20)
    at GulpPaths.src (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/GulpPaths.js:44:25)
    at getPaths (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/recipes/sass.js:33:33)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/tasks/recipes/sass.js:21:33)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/bootstrap/EnableExtension.js:16:18)
    at /Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/gulpfile.js:7:9
    at global.Elixir (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/index.js:21:5)
```

[image]

I thought that maybe there is something wrong with my `node_modules` directory, so I did `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` as usual. Everything was pulled but at the end I saw:

> ```
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY stream-browserify@*
> ```

[image]

I have no idea whether this unmet dependency is the reason. If this can help, this is the output of particular versions of the software I have:

`node -v`

> v7.0.0

`npm -v`

> 3.10.8

`gulp -v`

> [12:26:22] CLI version 3.9.1 
>   [12:26:22] Local version 3.9.1

Here is [my gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/komarnicki/269aa177d32495fcc48c94e811eb962a).

It doesn't like an array from `includePaths`? Can I ask for some help? Thank you.

edit:

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "slick",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047852/4197938

> The problem is that the options have been moved from the third to the
>   fourth parameter.

So I simply added additional `null` before `includePaths`.

> mix.sass('app.scss', null, null <- THIS IS THE SOLUTION, {

Then running `gulp` gave

```
$ gulp
[13:15:29] Using gulpfile ~/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/gulpfile.js
[13:15:29] Starting 'all'...
[13:15:29] Starting 'sass'...
[13:15:29] 'sass' errored after 60 ms
[13:15:29] Error: Missing binding /Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:15:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
[13:15:29] 'all' errored after 63 ms
[13:15:29] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(sass)'
Message:
    Missing binding /Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
Stack:
Error: Missing binding /Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:15:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/slick/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
```

so then I did exactly what was written in the output

`npm rebuild node-sass`

and the finally `gulp` did work

```
$ gulp
[13:20:18] Using gulpfile ~/Code/Komarnicki2/wp-content/themes/komarnicki/gulpfile.js
[13:20:18] Starting 'all'...
[13:20:18] Starting 'sass'...
[13:20:19] Finished 'sass' after 900 ms
[13:20:19] Starting 'scripts'...
[13:20:19] Finished 'scripts' after 96 ms
[13:20:19] Starting 'copy'...
[13:20:19] Finished 'copy' after 52 ms
[13:20:19] Starting 'version'...
[13:20:19] Finished 'version' after 56 ms
[13:20:19] Finished 'all' after 1.11 s
[13:20:19] Starting 'default'...
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Task          │ Summary                  │ Source Files                                                                │ Destination        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.sass()    │ 1. Compiling Sass        │ assets/sass/app.scss                                                        │ public/css/app.css │
│               │ 2. Autoprefixing CSS     │                                                                             │                    │
│               │ 3. Concatenating Files   │                                                                             │                    │
│               │ 4. Writing Source Maps   │                                                                             │                    │
│               │ 5. Saving to Destination │                                                                             │                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.scripts() │ 1. Concatenating Files   │ bower_components/fontfaceobserver/fontfaceobserver.js                       │ public/js/all.js   │
│               │ 2. Writing Source Maps   │ assets/js/font.loader.js                                                    │                    │
│               │ 3. Saving to Destination │ bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js                                  │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js                    │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/moment/moment.js                                           │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/moment/locale/pl.js                                        │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/bLazy/blazy.js                                             │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/jQuery-viewport-checker/dist/jquery.viewportchecker.min.js │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js                          │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.js                               │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js                          │                    │
│               │                          │ bower_components/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js               │                    │
│               │                          │ assets/js/scripts.js                                                        │                    │
│               │                          │ assets/js/modules/*.js                                                      │                    │
│               │                          │ assets/js/other/*.js                                                        │                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.copy()    │ 1. Saving to Destination │ assets/fonts//**/*                                                          │ public/fonts/      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.version() │ 1. Versioning            │ public/css/app.css                                                          │ public/build       │
│               │ 2. Rewriting File Paths  │ public/js/all.js                                                            │                    │
│               │ 3. Saving to Destination │                                                                             │                    │
│               │ 4. Copying Source Maps   │                                                                             │                    │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
[13:20:19] Finished 'default' after 6.65 ms
```

I still have no idea why all that happened. Was that because recently I was messing with `brew` stuff while creating [my shell scripts](https://github.com/mattkomarnicki/shell-scripts/blob/master/macOS/setup.sh) (`brew install node`)? It's great that my problem is solved but I'm unhappy by not knowing what caused it. Still can someone contribute and tell me what went wrong?

- Why the syntax has been changed?
- Why array of paths went to 4-th place in the list of args?
- How can I avoid that in the future?
- What if someone will decide to add 5th, 6th arg?

Was that because of dependency version mismatch? Now I'm affraid that this can happen in the future as well...